# Why virtual function has to be implemented in superclass?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
class X{
public:
    virtual void func();
};
class Y : public X{
public:
    virtual void func(){
        std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    Y* y = new Y();
    y->func();
    return 0;
}
```

But building fails (on Xcode - C++11) with the following messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for X", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Y in c.o
  "vtable for X", referenced from:
      X::() in c.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, as soon as I add an implementation for func in X, it builds successfully. I am pretty sure, that virtual method is optional to be implemented in the superclass but I don't understand why is this happening. Also, if comment the code in main(), it builds successfully. I am assuming that the problem is calling the func() in main, but Xcode doesn't list it as runtime error, it only says build-time error.

Comment: I imagine, you want pure virtual function?

Comment: Just a hint, in C++-speak a superclass is a `base` class, and a subclass is a `derived` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to implement the virtual function in the base class at all, simply mark it as pure virtual:

```
virtual void func() = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are wrong. You need to have implementations for non-*pure* virtual functions. If you do not want to provide an implementation, you need to make function pure virtual, using `= 0` syntax.